# Is there an English word for "the ability to be deleted"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there exists a correct English word for "the ability to delete something"?

The phrases I want to use this word in are:

> Toggle the option "that enables the object to be deleted."
>
> Toggle the "ability to delete" this file collection."

My first thought is "Deletability". But I'm unsure this is an correct word in English

> Toggle the deletability option of the object.
>
> Toggle the deletability of the file collection.

Is "deletability" a correct word? If not what would be an appropriate word?

---

**EDIT**:
added another phrase where i wanted to use "deletability" since the laste example was not so clear.

Comment: I'm imagining a checkbox. In which case I would have a concise label such as: "[ x ] Allow deletion".

Comment: I would use "deletable" for the option name.  Or "Allow deletion" is good, a Bad Horse suggests.

Comment: Your title asks for a different thing than your actual question. The ability to delete something is not the same as the ability _to be deleted_! The ability to delete something would more likely be a property of a user or user role (admin).

Comment: @oerkelens It appears you are correct. My question should reflect the ability of an object to be deleted. Since I'm not a native English speaker, nuances like this are often overlooked. Can I still change the question title to reflect this?

Comment: Sure, the current answers seem to focus on the _to be deleted_ option, so editing your title would not invalidate them. It certainly improves the quality of the question if title and question ask for the same thing — but it seems Brian beat you to it :)

Comment: Why has @BadHorsie's answer been deleted and transformed into a comment above? It had received 31 upvotes!

Comment: @Mari-LouA I wasn't involved in the deletion, but I'd assume it was because the question asks for an English word meaning "able to be deleted," not what a checkbox should be labeled on a UI.

Comment: @reirab if all answers that didn't specifically comply with the OP's requests were deleted, you can imagine the ensuing protests.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Abuse of mod power by RegDwigнt who deleted my post because I commented on his answer which then wasn't voted very highly.

Comment: @reirab I am clearly answering the question, with my suggestion being "Allow deletion" which according to a lot of people was the best suggestion. Sad state of affair here with the mods.

Comment: @BadHorsie I was curious to hear your side before jumping to conclusions. I don't think the mod in question is what I have heard called "a rep farmer" or a "rep hound", but I did notice that the deletion occurred around the time his answer was unaccepted, whether the deletion happened soon before or after the OP chose a different answer, I cannot say. And if the two actions are related, I cannot say.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The base English word you are looking for is "delible".  However, it is not commonly used.  You are best off with a different form as suggested in other answers.

Comment: An order of magnitude more English speakers will have heard the antonym, *indelible*, and that's still not commonly used.

Comment: This already existing word might be the one I need. It prevents me from possibly making up a word. The fact that it's not commonly used should not prevent it being used in my opinion.

Comment: @TempaC: your user testing will cover this anyway, but the problem with "delible" isn't just that it's rarely used (which I agree in itself doesn't matter much), it's that it'll rarely be understood. However, this being ELL rather than UX, a clever word that readers will need to look up in a dictionary is a perfectly reasonable answer :-)

Comment: Oh, and while you might well be able to rephrase to use this, you've requested a noun and "delible" is an adjective. If used as a noun it will mean "something that can be deleted", not "the ability of something to be deleted". Good luck with "delibility" in UX testing.

Answer (score 19):

A usable interface should not require to describe the actual action, because the action itself is obvious from the interface element: a radio button, check box, or any graphical toggle element, so a clear message may look:

> Enable **delete** option: On/Off

The word 'enable' implies toggling.

Example from Oracle Documentation

> [**15.1.2.2.1 Manually Enabling Delete Confirmation**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/fusionapps.1111/e15524/ui_impl_appfeat_ttt.htm)
>
> This section describes how to **enable Delete Confirmation**, or add or
>   edit the custom confirmation message, if you have an existing table.

Another option is to use 'removable':

> The element is **removable**: On/Off

Also a good convention (in console/command line interfaces) is putting a simple question:

> Enable deletion? Yes/No

Comment: 'Enable delete option' sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @bjb568 - It is not wrong and it is widely used, see "How to enable delete option on master slide layout" on http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-enable-delete-option-on-master-slide-layout.3401959/ and 27000 other Google results for "enable delete option" (with quotes to search for the phrase)

Comment: There's 49 million results for 'enable deletion option'…

Comment: @bjb568 - I included an example from official oracle documentation.

Comment: +1 for **removable**. I believe that's the word the OP is looking for.

Comment: "Enable deletion" or perhaps "Enable object deletion" also works in a GUI context.

Answer (score 11):

No. *Deletability* is morphologically fine and understandable in context, but it is not an established term (0 hits in COCA, 0 hits in BNC, 0 hits in OneLook) and you run the risk of sounding comical or helpless.

I can think of no other words that would fit the bill.

But all that is beside the point. The option to be toggled already *is* labeled or called something, and *that* is the label you must be using. This is techical documentation, not poetry. Refer to things by their actual names.

> Toggle the option "[the actual name of the option]".

If the option is actually called *deletability*, then go ahead and write "Toggle the option 'deletability'". But if it's not called that, then don't rephrase just for the sake of calling it something it's not called.

Comment: Actually, in a software context there is a real possibility the option is for a so far unspecified or unnamed entity, or is a global option applying to many options. From a design perspective, it can also look clumsy or verbose where everything is explicitly described.

Comment: Why did you delete my post? Are you mad because I left the above comment on your post in the early life of this thread? Talk about abuse of power.

Answer (score 7):

You also might turn the property around. "Deletability", while understandable, sounds a bit awkward. However, objects that cannot be deleted are often referred to in the computer sciences as "Protected", so you might consider toggling "Protection" or "Deletion Protection" (or sometimes "Write Protection" for files) on or off instead.

Answer (score 6):

Permission is a common notion used in software world. You can use something like 'Delete Permission', or you can rephrase the sentence to

> Toggle the delete permission on the object

or

> Toggle permission to delete object

Answer (score 3):

10 seconds in Dictionary.app produced `deletable`. that word beside a checkbox will be completely clear to anyone even reasonably fluent in English

Answer (score 2):

Remove|Removable. Erase|Erasable. Delete|Deletable.

Though 'Allow deletion' may be preferred aesthetically in a GUI styled toward artists/humanists (?).

Stay consistent.

Answer (score 2):

"Allow delete option" sounds meta, as in it allows someone to allow someone else to delete it, since there are two words that basically imply a granting of permission.

tldr: "permit X" and "permit permitting of X" are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

How about

Toggle the delete option ?

or

Allow delete option ?

or

Allow option to delete object?

or

object deletable?

Answer (score 0):

Guarded or Protected, if toggled off, would indicate that the object is now subject to annihilation.

Comment: So your answer is "subject to annihilation"?

Comment: This whole website is subject to annihilation!